# how to customize post in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to customize my own post using the shortcode way in wordpress. I want to display the post according to its category.

```
<?php

function sample_post($atts) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'category_name' => 'uncategorized'
   ), $atts));

  $args = array('category_name' => $category_name);
   query_posts($args);
   if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
         <label><?php the_title(); ?></label>
   <?php
        endwhile;
   endif;
}

add_shortcode('sample_post', 'sample_post');

?>
```

the code is fine and I have a file in my template name `content-page.php`
here is the code of my content-page

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'unite' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );

            edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'foodgrower' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

I don't know if I miss something about the setup or query on it. Here's I really want to displays. I only want to display `<label><?php the_title(); ?></label>` (the title of the post), but now it displays the content-page.php. I don't get it also why it appears in my page. I didn't call the content-page.php to display in my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to return the data, like the following,

```
function sample_post($atts) {
   $return = '';
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'category_name' => 'uncategorized'
   ), $atts));

  $args = array('category_name' => $category_name);
   $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
   if ($the_query->have_posts()) : while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
         $return .= "<label>".the_title()."</label>";
        endwhile;
   endif;
   return $return;
}

add_shortcode('sample_post', 'sample_post');
```

Comment: still content_page.php is working. it's still same result

Comment: The problem looks different. Try to switch out it with WP_Query(). Can I give you an example?

Comment: can you give sample for that